# jQuery error on binding - CSS not being applied to dynamically generated class

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, anchor

I'm trying to bind some css using jQuery to an element in an AngularJS app using the following function:

```
$scope.showZone = function(obj)
        {
            var zone = obj.srcElement.id;
            if($("."+zone).attr("zone") == "true")
            {
                $("svg."+zone).fadeOut();
                $(obj.toElement).removeClass("active");
                $("."+zone).attr('zone', "false");
            }
            else
            {
                $("svg."+zone).fadeIn();
                $(obj.toElement).addClass("active");
                $("."+zone).attr("zone", "true");
            }

        };
```

This is the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in zoneCollection | unique:'zone' | filter:searchZone">
    <a href="" id="{{i.zone.replace(' ','').replace('/','')}}" ng-click="showZone($event)" class="listButton">
        <span class="circle" style="background: #31dbd2"></span>
        <span class="zoneName">{{i.zone}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

It works fine generally, but when I click on the text in the anchor tag, I get the following error.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
    at Function.Sizzle.error (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:1437:8)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2051:11)
    at Sizzle.select (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2452:20)
    at Function.Sizzle (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:843:9)
    at jQuery.fn.extend.find (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2668:11)
    at jQuery.fn.init (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2776:38)
    at jQuery (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js:76:10)
    at Scope.$scope.showZone (http://localhost:8080/build/src/app/planManager/planManger.js:2065:21)
    at Parser.functionCall (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/angular/angular.js:10567:21)
    at http://localhost:8080/build/vendor/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:441:9
```

Also, when the 'active' class is being added to the anchor tag, my CSS is not being applied to the tag, although the 'active' class itself is reflecting on the DOM.

```
a.listButton.active
{
    background-color: #ffd348;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 43px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need jQuery for this? From experience it is better not to mix angular and jQuery unless it is absolutely necessary they don not play well with each other.

Answer (score 1):

DOM manipulation should be done only by directives (I'm guessing `showZone` is in a Controller).

Instead of directly adding/removing classes, try using the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="zone in zoneCollection | unique:'zone' | filter:searchZone">
    <a ng-click="activeZone=zone" class="listButton" ng-class="{active:activeZone===zone}">
        <span class="circle" style="background: #31dbd2"></span>
        <span class="zoneName">{{zone.name}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

SVG:

```
<svg>
  <circle
      ng-repeat="zone in zoneCollection | unique:'zone' | filter:searchZone"
      ng-class="{active-zone:activeZone===zone}"
  >
  </circle>
</svg>
```

(be aware of [SVG restrictions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings))

JS: none :)